# connecting to SQL Server 2008 using php pdo

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am working with the `SQL Server 2008` and `php pdo`. I am trying to connect from `php` to `sql server 2008`.

my **php version** is:**5.5.12**

> I am getting error :: could not find driver

what I tried is to `connect to sql server 2008 database` from `php` like:

```
<?php
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "xxxxxx";
$dbuser     = "xx";
$dbpass     = "";
try {

   $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I also surfed a lot but did not found the solution.
my extensions in php.ini

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

location where i put the dll is C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext

Comment: did you get a chance to check this http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php? You have not downloaded the driver

Comment: ok thank u.. but where to put that php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and how to configure them in php.ini

Comment: @satya yes now i have downloaded the drivers an also put it into the extension.. still its not working and giving same error.. could not find driver

Comment: have you restarted Apache

Comment: @satya yes  i am trying for so long. i have restarted appache. every time i made change to php.ini. i have tried both thread safe dll and not thread safe dll stil not working